# How to update some application to latest version with homebrew-cask?

Tags: terminal, upgrade, software-update, homebrew, package-management

I noticed some packages provided by homebrew-cask uses a url of the latest version and a version number of "latest" such as [dropbox](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/dropbox.rb) and [chrome](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/google-chrome.rb). Thus they will never be upgraded with `brew upgrade`. Is there any simple way to update such packages using homebrew-cask?

And if I call `brew cask install dropbox` again, it shows there already exist some cache of old version, which I feel so dumb.

Comment: have you tried `brew update`

Comment: @Greg is wrong about this, read http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230754/1916

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this command:

```
brew cask install dropbox --force
```

Please consider [logging a bug](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/issues) over at [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) about your concerns with updating this kind of cask.

Comment: https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/issues/309, still in discussion

Comment: is it safe to use? does it cleanly remove the old version while keeping its configuration?

Comment: @ErikAllik your comment will unlikely to be seen here by the **brew cask** developers. Please can you start a new question or log a bug with [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) directly.

Answer (score 0):

As of today brew cask does not implement upgrade but there is an open issue that tracks this at https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/4678

If you want to see it implemented sooner you could add your small contribution by fixing one of the todo items listed there.

Answer (score 0):

This has really irked me so I created this script to update all Brew apps and allow the user to choose which Cask apps to update. You can exclude apps from consideration too.

https://github.com/derrekyoung/ScriptsAndUtils/blob/master/brew-cask-upgrade.sh

Answer (score 0):

```
brew upgrade --cask dropbox
```

I find this to be the most convenient way of upgrading a specific app using brew.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).